# Sum the expression

Tags: reporting-services, sum

I need to sum this expression

```
= IIf(Fields!SupplyStrategyTypeName.Value="Supply",0,
IIf(Fields!IP_DA_FIN.Value>225,Fields!IP_DA_FIN.Value-225,0))
```

I tried following the example of the previous question but I get an error.

Any help on this?

Comment: What error? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Excel formulas are probably off-topic here...

Comment: What server are you using? Please tag your questions with the most information possible - this enables more people to help you.

Comment: @mustaccio Looks like SSRS to me

Comment: I knew that exclamation mark notation was strange.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list what you tried or the error you got so here's what should work:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!SupplyStrategyTypeName.Value = "Supply", 0,
     IIf(Fields!IP_DA_FIN.Value > 225, Fields!IP_DA_FIN.Value - 225, 0)) )
```

So if a row of data's **SupplyStrategyTypeName** is **Supply** or **IP_DA_FIN** is 225 or less, it would result in 0 otherwise it would be IP_DA_FIN - 225. Then the sum will sum all the results.

Don't be worried about using too many spaces - they make it more readable when you go back through your formulas to figure out what's wrong.